# antlr - loop through nodes

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the following grammar (simplified):

```
filter   : eq | and;

eq       : 'eq' '(' property ',' value ')';

and      : 'and' '(' filter ',' filter (',' filter)* ')';

...
```

I am parsing simple prefix constructions like:

```
and(eq(name,john),eq(location,usa))
```

What is the best way to loop through the `filter` nodes of a `and` node? The generated class `AndContext` has a function `filter(int index)`, but nothing more. I want to do something like:

```
AndContext c = ...;

for (int i = 0; i < c.numberOfFilters(); ++i) {
    FilterContext f = c.filter(i);
}
```

There is the function `getChildCount()`, but it returns the count of all nodes (including the terminal nodes representing `(`, `)`, etc.), and not just the interesting `filter` nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your grammar looks like this:

```antlr
grammar F;

eq       : 'eq' '(' property ',' value ')';
and      : 'and' '(' filter ',' filter (',' filter)* ')';
filter   : eq | and;
property : 'name' | 'location';
value    : 'john' | 'usa';
```

then you could extend the generated `FBaseListener` and override its `enterAnd` to get to the `FilterContext`s:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FLexer lexer = new FLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("and(eq(name,john),eq(location,usa))"));
        FParser parser = new FParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new AndListener(), parser.and());
    }
}

class AndListener extends FBaseListener {

    @Override
    public void enterAnd(@NotNull FParser.AndContext ctx) {
        for (FParser.FilterContext filterContext : ctx.filter()) {
            System.out.println("filterContext=" + filterContext.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

which will print:

```
filterContext=eq(name,john)
filterContext=eq(location,usa)
```

Comment: The key piece included in this answer that the OP missed is the existence of `AndContext.filter()` in addition to the method `AndContext.filter(int)` which was mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I totally overlooked that `filter()` function. I thought there was only a `filter(int index)` function.

Comment: FWIW, I am not using the walker/listener way of parsing, as I am recursively converting the parse tree into my `pojo tree`.

Comment: @SteveKelio, yeah, I wasn't sure how you are (or were) planning to traverse the tree, so in case you weren't familiar with tree-listeners I decided to post a small example. Good to hear you have a solution.

Comment: That was very thoughtful. Thanks for answer.